# Restore UI state after submitting HTML form

Tags: jquery, html

Actually I am dynamically creating list items under ul using jquery.

```
$.each(alltags.departments,function(){
   $("#specialitycenters").append('<li>'+this+'</li>');
});
```

Here specialitycenters is my ul id. Am appending list items using my alltags.departments(comes from ajax call).

So am adding class "selected" whenever we click on a list item. If there are 10 list items and I have clicked 3 li's then am adding class "selected" to those 3 li's.

```
var lis = $('.list ul#specialitycenters li').click(function(e){
if(!e.ctrlKey) {
    // Ctrl not pressed, clear previous selections
     lis.removeClass("selected");      
}
$(this).addClass("selected");    
});
});
```

Now when I submit my form these dynamically added classes are reverting back. But I need to keep the "selected" class to the clicked list items even after clicking submit button. How can I acheve this?

Comment: When you say "when I submit my form these dynamically added classes are reverting back", are you actually submitting the form and reloading the page?

Comment: Yes am submitting the form and reloading the page then the added classes are disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, when you submit a form, the browser submits the data to the server and loads a brand new version of the page the data was sent to.

You have two options:

1. **Don't submit the form, use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the data to the server (best option, do this one)**
2. Before submitting the form, store some data regarding the sate of your UI in the browser using cookies or local storage etc, submit the form, use the stored data to reset your UI (you can, but dont, this is what ajax is for...)